# I get a runtime error in my code of how to find if an array can be become non decreasing by modifying at most one element

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

> Given an array with `n` integers, your task is to check if it could become non-decreasing by modifying at most 1 element.
>   We define an array is non-decreasing if `array[i] <= array[i + 1]` holds for every `i` `(1 <= i < n)`.

My code is the one below. I get a runtime error while I run but I can not identify what the error is. I am quite new to programming so please specify in the simplest way possible if you find what goes wrong. Thank you.

```
class Solution {
public:
  bool checkPossibility(vector<int> &nums) {
    bool status = false;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i <= nums.size() - 2; i++) {
      if (nums[i] > nums[i + 1]) {
        count++;
      }
    }
    if (count > 1) {
      status = false;
    } else {
      status = true;
    }

    return status;
  }
};
```

I get a runtime overflow error.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This `i <= nums.size()` is an error. The overflow case arises when `i== nums.size()`

Comment: Check behavior on the input `{11, 12, 1, 2}`.

Comment: @Ripi2 The condition you are complaining about is `i <= nums.size() - 2`, not `i <= nums.size()`. Subtracting 2 allows the subscript `i+1` inside the loop, in most cases. (OK, it took me two reads to notice that myself.)

Comment: @Maru your question would be improved if it included the vector you use when you get the overflow error. There are many vectors for which is does not overflow, so the input is highly relevant. (See [mcve].)

Comment: @JaMiT yes exactly its i <= .size() - 2. Well, the test case i get overflow error is [4, 2, 3]. Although i think my code needs fixing because i have to take 2 test cases when count = 1. It is a problem published in leetcode.com

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nums.size()` is unsigned. If the size is smaller than 2, `size() - 2` will overflow and return a very large number, thus you will go out of bounds.

You can solve this simply by moving the 2 to the other side: `i + 2 <= nums.size()`

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense. Although i think my else case needs fixing because when count = 1 it doesn't always give correct results